# Match a dot/period if not followed AND preceded by a single character

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

So I know I need to use the lookahead and lookbehind stuff, but I'm starting to lose my mind.

Therefore, can you provide an example, and an explanation of what it means.

I need to match the dots in the following sequence, but not that ones in between the individual characters.

```
this.is.a.sentence.e.g.
```

When removing the matched dots you should be left with:

```
this is a sentence e.g
```

The answer needs to work in a variety of different regex engines, so something generic is preferred, but if it's easier, I'm sure I can work it out from a .NET based one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lookbehinds are not widely supported, and your requirements make it difficult not to use them.  Perhaps a superior regex guru can provide a solution that does not use them, but for now here is what I have:

```
(?:        # do not capture
 ^         # anchor to start of line
 |         # alternation
 (?<=      # lookbehind
  [^.]{2}  # two non-period characters
 )
)
\.         # a literal period
|          # alternation
\.         # a literal period
(?:        # do not capture
 $         # anchor to end of line
 |         # alternation
 (?=       # lookahead
  [^.]{2}  # two non-period characters
 )
)
```

Essentially this does two alternating checks:  A period that is preceded either by the start of the line *or* two non-period characters, ***or*** a period that is followed either by the end of the line *or* two non-period characters.

This works for your specific example: http://rubular.com/r/3ueTN37Smh

You could also handle doing the replacement this way:

```
s/(^|[^.]{2})\.|\.($|[^.]{2})/\1 \2/
```

This captures the two preceeding or following characters instead and inserts them back as part of the match.  It's simpler and probably available for more languages.

Comment: The only popular language that you'd need to worry about this one not working in would be javascript.. other than that, it should work well across engines.

Comment: thanks, That does indeed work, however, please can you break it down and explain, as I said in the question, I want to know how it works, not just the answer (show your workings as my maths teacher used to say)

Comment: @Martin added the explanation